# Java webapp can't write image to folder created by webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, centos

I have a web application, I have several actions. One of the actions writes some image to a folder out of context, lets say to:

/home/user/images/subfolder1/image.jpg

Now, another action copies that image to another folder located inside images, but with a different extension, lets say to:

/home/user/images/subfolder2/subsubfolder2-1/image.png

Now, the first image is get from a form, the second image is get from the path where the first image was saved, both images are written with the same method:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination.getAbsolutePath());

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
   out.write(buf, 0, len);
}
```

The webapp creates every folder, including "subfolder2/subsubfolder2-1/" using mkdirs() if they don't exist.

This works just fine in my test enviroment running ubuntu 14.04 with apache tomcat 6.0.43, but, on production, is centos 6(or 6.5), same apache tomcat version, the image is created, but no data is written to it, what  I mean, is that a image.png file is created, but its size is 0. All folders have the correct permissions, drwxrwxrwx, but image.png for some reason, lacks them, having only rw.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Try turnning the log level to trace and if you see anything suspicious. From the info you have shared it seems like some local environment setup issue - kind of difficult to answer

Comment: The only thing I get in my logs is when I try to read the file, I get that file or directory doesn't exist, I guess isFile validates size, and as it is 0, it returns that it doesn't exist. But I'll try changing log level.

Comment: Are you sure that you are closing the output stream correctly?

Comment: Yeah, I'm closing properly, but I already fixed it. Very strangely. Going to add answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some uknown reason, I just changed how I write my file to:

```
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(origen);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destination.getAbsolutePath());

        int byteRead = 0;
           byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
           while ((byteRead = in.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1){
               out.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
            }
```

And it worked properly, don't know the reason behind it.